# ggbiplot - how to change colour of vectors

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggbiplot

Is it possible to change colour of the variables (vectors and their names) shown in ggbiplot? There is such option for observations, but I cannot find one for variables.
Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking to change the color of each vector individually? Or just all of the vectors to a single color?

Comment: Where is the code that loads the library and creates an example?

Comment: I want to change the colour to black for all vectors.